# Installing MongoDb on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails, deployment, mongodb

I'm trying to deploy a Rails 3.2.3 with MondoDb app to EC2. I've chosen `t2.micro` instance. However, I found out that to use MonboDb I have to use at least `m1.large` - https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/ordering?productId=6a12917c-d481-43a6-9c7a-619eeec4545a&ref_=dtl_psb_continue&region=us-east-1

So the question is how do I actually install MongoDb on EC2: do I have to buy it and setup at the link above suggests or just manually download it from 10gen's website and install the same way I would do on my local machine? If the first option, will I necessarily have to use `m1.large` instance instead of `t2.micro`?

Comment: You're installing on an EC2 instance, not on AWS. EC2 instances are no different than any other linux server. Find an installation guide for your distribution and follow it.

Comment: @EEAA, I followed it and that lead me to the question I asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking at [this link?](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00CO7AVMY/ref=gtw_msl_sim__B00CO7AVMY_2/190-7954499-1604038?ie=UTF8&pf_rd_r=0AGTQMVTTDCK8DTSNWRY&pf_rd_m=A33KC2ESLMUT5Y&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_i=awsmp-gateway-1&pf_rd_p=1549113282&pf_rd_s=center-3) Based on my read, that's so you can buy a canned mongoDB-on-a-server with pre-configured storage and other things. If you just want to install MongoDB on a box, make sure the ec2 instance you want to run meets the MongoDB requirements and go from there. t2 Micro servers are (in my experience) pretty OK if you're not looking for high performance.

Comment: so there're 2 ways to install MongoDb: buy it from the link you gave or install it myself downloading from 10gen's website?

Comment: At least two, yup.

Comment: do you mind taking a look at this? http://serverfault.com/questions/628408/connecting-to-mongodb-at-ec2-how-do-i-know-username-host-port-ect

Comment: Alex, the link you attached refers to installing it on an Ubuntu EC2 instance. If you have RHEL family OS like Fedora or default Amazon OS, you should follow the [following](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/) instructions. Remember that EC2 is IAAS, so it just provides a blank box, on which you manage installation etc. The configuration of that box will come from your database requirement, while AMI has some pre-configured specs. Specs of AMI are recommendations from MongoDB and Amazon, but you don't need to follow it, if that will lead

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB Community edition is opensource and free. t2.micro is typically for test purpose or light load, not recommended for the production usage. It would be better to use m1.large for MongoDB. Also it is usually better to run the application and database on the separate instances.

The CloudStax FireCamp is a good way to deploy a MongoDB Cluster. Please refer to this answer for details, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45000300/8280034.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the manual configuration and AMI configuration you can use a deployment service like [Deploy4Me](https://deploy4me.com). It is just a better way to configure AWS. You can configure Ruby and MongoDB to be installed on the same server. So, you would receive a fully configured environment with some extra perks like security and proper Linux configuration.